# Replace integers in a column by matching other columns in R

Tags: r, match

I have data frames:

```
One <- data.frame(Numb = 1:10, Dog = c(4,2,6,3,8,4,6,8,4,9))
Two <- data.frame(Number = c(3,5,7,9,2,4,65,8,1,23,6,10,99), Cat = rep(NA, 13))
```

I want to write the numbers from `One$Dog` to `Two$Cat` so that the numbers in the first row would match. Like this:

```
Number   Cat
     3     6
     5     8
     7     6
     9     4
     2     2
     4     3
    65    NA
     8     8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `match` the `Number` and `Numb` in 'Two' and 'One' to get the numeric index, use that to get the 'Dog' elements.

```
Two$Cat <- One$Dog[match(Two$Number, One$Numb)]
head(Two,8)
#  Number Cat
#1      3   6
#2      5   8
#3      7   6
#4      9   4
#5      2   2
#6      4   3
#7     65  NA
#8      8   8
```